# runtime custom rpc is not taking "at" params as optional

Tags: polkadot-js, custom-rpc

I have an rpc

```
#[rpc]
pub trait ShivarthuApi<BlockHash> {
    #[rpc(name = "shivarthu_challengerevidence")]
    fn get_challengers_evidence(
        &self,
        at: Option<BlockHash>,
        profile_citizenid: u128,
        offset: u64,
        limit: u16,
    ) -> Result<Vec<u128>>;
}
```

With curl when I pass null it gives results

```
curl http://localhost:9933 -H "Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8" -d   '{
     "jsonrpc":"2.0",
      "id":1,
      "method":"shivarthu_challengerevidence",
      "params": [null, 0, 0, 5]
    }'
```

But without null, it gives error:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32602,"message":"Invalid params: invalid type: number, expected a (both 0x-prefixed or not) hex string with length of 64."},"id":1}
```

But with my front end code using polkadot js it gives error with null or undefined:

```
 const api2 = await ApiPromise.create({
        provider: wsProvider,
        rpc: {
          shivarthu: {
            challengerevidence: {
              description: 'Challenger Evidence',
              params: [
                {
                  name: 'at',
                  type: 'Hash',
                  isOptional: true,
                },
                {
                  name: 'profile_citizenid',
                  type: 'u128',
                },
                {
                  name: 'offset',
                  type: 'u64',
                },
                {
                  name: 'limit',
                  type: 'u16',
                },
              ],
              type: 'Vec<u128>',
            },
          },
        },
      })
   

      let data = await api2.rpc.shivarthu.challengerevidence(null, 0, 0, 5)
      console.log(data)
```

Error:

```
index.js:73 Uncaught (in promise) Error: 9876: Something wrong: Application, UnknownBlock, Header was not found in the database: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe there is an issue where the JS API only expects the optional `at` param as the very last one - basically the de-facto standard order of RPC params in  Substrate itself.

So basically the form it is used to dealing with and caters for is the following -

```rust
#[rpc]
pub trait ShivarthuApi<BlockHash> {
    #[rpc(name = "shivarthu_challengerevidence")]
    fn get_challengers_evidence(
        &self,
        profile_citizenid: u128,
        offset: u64,
        limit: u16,
        at: Option<BlockHash>,
    ) -> Result<Vec<u128>>;
}
```

An additional tip, for the `at` params, also add the `isHistoric: true` (in adition to the existing `isOptional`) flag to the JS API definition. It indicates to the API that this param may be indicate results from older blocks with different runtime/types.

Once defined for calling, it means it should be completely omitted when not needed -

```js
// no hash, no param
let data = await api2.rpc.shivarthu.challengerevidence(0, 0, 5)

// hash, add param
let data = await api2.rpc.shivarthu.challengerevidence(0, 0, 5, 0x...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are changes to be made, moving `at` to the last:

```
#[rpc]
pub trait ShivarthuApi<BlockHash> {
    #[rpc(name = "shivarthu_challengerevidence")]
    fn get_challengers_evidence(
        &self,
        profile_citizenid: u128,
        offset: u64,
        limit: u16,
        at: Option<BlockHash>,
    ) -> Result<Vec<u128>>;
}
```

Similarly, keep `at` as last argument here in `get_challengers_evidence`:

```
impl<C, Block> ShivarthuApi<<Block as BlockT>::Hash> for Shivarthu<C, Block>
where
    Block: BlockT,
    C: Send + Sync + 'static,
    C: ProvideRuntimeApi<Block>,
    C: HeaderBackend<Block>,
    C::Api: ShivarthuRuntimeApi<Block>,
{

    fn get_challengers_evidence(
        &self,      
        profile_citizenid: u128,
        offset: u64,
        limit: u16,
        at: Option<<Block as BlockT>::Hash>,
    ) -> Result<Vec<u128>> {
        let api = self.client.runtime_api();
        let at = BlockId::hash(at.unwrap_or_else(||
            // If the block hash is not supplied assume the best block.
            self.client.info().best_hash));

        let runtime_api_result =
            api.get_challengers_evidence(&at, profile_citizenid, offset, limit);
        runtime_api_result.map_err(|e| RpcError {
            code: ErrorCode::ServerError(9876), // No real reason for this value
            message: "Something wrong".into(),
            data: Some(format!("{:?}", e).into()),
        })
    }
}
```

But `&at` should be first argument in `let runtime_api_result = api.get_challengers_evidence(&at, profile_citizenid, offset, limit)`, otherwise it gives compilation error.

And move `at` to the last in params in polkadotjs, otherwise it gives error,

```
const api2 = await ApiPromise.create({
        provider: wsProvider,
        rpc: {
          shivarthu: {
            challengerevidence: {
              description: 'Challenger Evidence',
              params: [
                {
                  name: 'profile_citizenid',
                  type: 'u128',
                },
                {
                  name: 'offset',
                  type: 'u64',
                },
                {
                  name: 'limit',
                  type: 'u16',
                },
                {
                  name: 'at',
                  type: 'Hash',
                  isOptional: true,
                  isHistoric: true,
                },
              ],
              type: 'Vec<u128>',
            },
          },
        },
      })
```

Then `at` becomes optional and gives no error:

```
 let data = await api2.rpc.shivarthu.challengerevidence(0, 0, 5)
 console.log(data.toString())
```